# executeFetchRequest return nil on empty core data

Tags: ios, core-data

I encountered a weird issue in Core Data. Basically, I have an empty core data with several models like Student and Teacher. I tried to execute the code below:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Student"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(username = %@) AND (password = %@)", username, password];

// Determines if there is a match for student
NSError *error;
NSArray *matches = [self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (error || !matches || [matches count] > 1) {
    NSLog(@"Error in retrieving login match for student");
}
else if ([matches count]) {
    student = [matches firstObject];
}
```

The weird thing is that `matches` turns out to be `nil` and the error message gets printed out. Shouldn't matches be an empty array since an empty core data would just mean that the context couldn't find the NSManagedObject that satisfied those conditions?

Comment: Have you tried logging error? Your if statement doesn't distinguish between matches being nil or an error occurring.

Comment: Yeah, I actually did a NSLog statement before the if condition checking for nil and it returned true.

Comment: What was nil? error or matches?

Comment: If by result you mean the matches array, it should be nil if there was an error. So, you need to log error, and see if it gives you anything.

Comment: When I log the error, it gives me (null).

Comment: Hmmm... that's curious then. As far as I can tell, you should get an empty array. When I tried it with an empty core data model, I got an empty array.

Comment: Actually, when I started to look into this further I noticed that my self.context was nil and made changes to fix my problem by setting it. Sorry for putting this as an issue with core data. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer = yes, it should.

According to [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/executeFetchRequest:error:):

> Return Value of executeFetchRequest ... An array of objects that meet the criteria specified by request
>   fetched from the receiver and from the persistent stores associated
>   with the receiver’s persistent store coordinator. **If an error occurs**,
>   **returns nil**. **If no objects** match the criteria specified by request,
>   returns an **empty array**.

Therefore, check your NSError

Comment: Seconds after posting I got it: my `NSManagedObjectContext` was also `nil`